# Angular 2.0 integration with Payment gateway via iFrame

Tags: angular, payment-gateway

Withing our Angular 2 framework, we have integrated with a payment gateway using an `iframe`. Integration works fine.

However, after entering the card details, when the user clicks on the submit button, we want to show a progress bar (or a pop-up mentioning not to click the back button). We are struggling with this since the main page does not have control over the events within the `iframe`.

Though we did not want to use JQuery, we tried it anyway. However, this impacted the performance of the application.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <iframe *ngIf="currentFrameUrl" id="contentFrame" [src]="currentFrameUrl | safe" #iframe></iframe>
```

And

```
    export class ContentFrameComponent implements OnInit {
  currentFrameUrl: string;
  currentMenuState: boolean;
  @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

  constructor(private frameService: ContentFrameService) {
    this.currentMenuState = true;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.frameService.providerCurrentUrl$.subscribe(data => this.currentFrameUrl = data);
    this.frameService.providerMenuState$.subscribe(data => this.currentMenuState = data);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
    if (typeof doc.addEventListener !== undefined) {
      doc.addEventListener("click", this.iframeClickHandler, false)
    } else if (typeof doc.attachEvent !== undefined) {
      doc.attachEvent("onclick", this.iframeClickHandler);
    }
  }

  iframeClickHandler() {
    alert("Iframe clicked");
  }
}
```